# Why do I keep getting an infinite loop whenever a non-integer type is inputted?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
 * GETOP -- get an integer operand; we do operation-specific checks later
 *
 * parameters: opno     the number of the operand (as in 1st, 2nd, etc.)
 * returns: int         the integer value of the operand just read
 * exceptions: none */

int getop(int opno) 

 { 
    int val; 
    int rv; /* value returned from scanf */
            /* a
             * loop until you get an integer or EOF
             *
             * prompt and read a value */
    do{
        /* prompt and read a value */
        printf("\toperand %d: ", opno);
        rv = scanf("%d", &val);
        /* oops */
        if (rv == 0)
        {
            printf("\toperand must be an integer\n");
            /* loop until a valid value */
        }
        while (rv == 0);
            /*
             * if it's EOF, say so and quit
             */
        if (rv == EOF)
        {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

     /*
             * otherwise, say what you read
             */
        return(val);


    }
```

/* When I wrote rv == 0, it keeps giving me an infinite loop. Am I writing something wrong or is there another way to check for non-integers without the program going into an infinite loop? */

Answer (score 2):

Because when `scanf` sees input that doesn't match its format, it simply stops reading, and leaves the invalid input in the buffer. So next time you try to read, you will attempt to read the exact same invalid input again, and again, and...

A simple solution is to read a line using `fgets` and then use `sscanf` to get the data.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks!

Comment: Or check the return from `scanf`, which will tell you how many format codes were successfully parsed.